# How to align two different labels to center? (Windows Form App)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, alignment

I have two labels on my screen. One must be a little higher than another. I can't combine them to one because of different formatting, so I set Dock property to Fill and its not working (one label overlaps another).

Comment: Put them in  a Panel, one docked top the other bottom. then center the Panel. Not seeing anything we can relly know what you need.

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually I have only two labels on my screen. During program running text changes on this labels (length and quantity of lines changes). That's why I have to resize labels. But if I set property `AutoSize ` `true` - labels resizes relative to the left top edge, so that they aren't at the center of screen

Comment: You need to state clearly what layout you want: Are the labels besides each other or above and below?

Comment: One is above than another. Labels have to be symmetrically along the horizontal axis. I have found solution: make label much wider, than the maximum length of text, set `TextAlign` as `MiddleCenter`, and set `AutoSize` `false`, but i'm not sure, is that way right or not.

Comment: Well in that case my 1st comment is a way to go. adding a panel for layout purposes is quite a normal thing, btw.. Dock the Panel to the Top of the form! Of course the labels need to have a centered textalign. __You could also dock both labels to the top. This should work without the extra layout panel. Not the one created first will sit at the top, the second one below.__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextAlign` property on the label will align the text with respect to its own size. If `AutoSize` is set to `true` the size will be as small as possible so you won't see any changes for alignment.

Try setting `AutoSize` to `false`, `TextAlign` to `MiddleCenter`, then either resize/position your controls as you like (bad if the parent control resizes), or try setting `Dock` to `Top` or `Bottom`.

If you want more control over the vertical position you could try putting your Labels in a `TableLayoutPanel`, then you set `Dock` to `Fill` for each label in their separate cells.